# How to add Google Map markers from getJSON array?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

My array from a PHP file looks like this:

```
[
 {"lat":"4.174475","lon":"73.509564","datetime":"2012-11-23 16:41:40"},
 {"lat":"5.17","lon":"73.50633754680894","datetime":"2012-11-23 05:00:00"},
 {"lat":"6.17","lon":"73.50633754680894","datetime":"2012-11-01 00:00:00"}
]
```

When I click the link #Three, it should generate 3 markers using the `threeClick()` function. Here is the function.

```
function threeClick () {
  $.getJSON('json.search.php?idcard=<?php echo $idcardno; ?>&limit=3', function(data) {
    var location;
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
      addMarker(val.lat,val.lon);
    });
  }
```

The add marker function is like this (from: [Plotting LatLng coordinates from Json Array on Google Map --- the markers all stack up in the same location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366861/plotting-latlng-coordinates-from-json-array-on-google-map-the-markers-all-st))

```
function addMarker(lat,lng) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
    map: map,
    icon: "images/mapIcons/red-dot.png"
  });
  markersArray.push(marker);
}
```

I generated the map using:

```
var map;
var markersArray = [];
function initMap() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(4.174475, 73.509564);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), myOptions);
}
```

Can anybody suggest me how I can show the markers on click of a link? What is wrong with this code?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted. Please edit your post and add in the code you used for the event handler (the code that captures clicks on `#Three` and calls the `threeClick()` function).

Comment: Also, as @Andreas pointed out, please also include a description of the problem you encountered, including any error messages (or lack thereof).

Comment: @BenLee i used <a id="Three" onclick="threeClick" >three</a> . the problem is the markers arent coming

Comment: @jinni, do you see any error messages in the javascript console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you used this:

```
<a id="Three" onclick="threeClick">three</a>
```

The problem is that `threeClick` by itself doesn't actually call the function. It just references it. You need parenthesis to call it, like this:

```
<a id="Three" onclick="threeClick()">three</a>
```

But it would be even better to use jQuery to attach the handler. So set your html like this:

```
<a id="Three" href="#">three</a>
```

And then add this to your javascript:

```
$('#Three').click(function() {
    threeClick();
    return false;
});
```

Note that the `return false` here is to prevent the '#' click default action (setting the url hash) from happening.

Comment: Yeah. I missed that. But I used onclick="threeClick()" and it did not work

Comment: i have accepted your answer because you were the one who suggested to check javascript console. the problem was a missing bracket ) at the end  of the click function. my mistake :D