# Add multiple markers to google maps from json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, maps

I am trying to build a web app that pulls data from server and adds multiple markers to the google map from the JSON response. This is how the JSON response looks like:

```
{"key":[{"Latitude":"60.186518","Longitude":"24.950575"}...]}
```

I tried to implement the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366861/plotting-latlng-coordinates-from-json-array-on-google-map-the-markers-all-st) but I can't get it to work.

This is my code so far:

```
    function success(position) {
  var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
  mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
  mapcanvas.style.height = '600px';

  document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);
  var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  var options = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: coords,
      panControl: false,
  zoomControl: false,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  scaleControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  overviewMapControl: true,

    navigationControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coords,
      map: map,
      title:"You are here!"});

 function getLocations() {

    $.getJSON("http://myurl.com/jsonresponse", function (json) {

        var location;


        $.each(json.key, function (i, item) {
            addMarker(item.Latitude,item.Longitude);
        });

    });
}

function addMarker(lat,lng) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            map: map,
        });
        markersArray.push(marker);
}

}
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
} else {
  error('Geo Location is not supported');
}
```

Comment: What is not working? If you debug, which errors do you get?

Comment: If you have a lot of markers I suggest you to use a KML file...

Comment: Currenty i have 36 markers. And i dont seem to get any errors. I think there is something wrong with the addmarker function, but i am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

> ```
>       function getLocations() {
>             $.ajax({
>               url: 'http://myurl.com/jsonresponse',
>               async:false,
>               success: function(data) {
>                  $.each(data.key, function(index) {
>                     addMarker(data[index].Latitude,data[index].Longitude);
>                   });
>               }
>             }); 
>         }
> ```

Other wise use console.log(lat,lng) in addMarker function and copy the output here.

Comment: When i add console.log to addMarker like this:

`function addMarker(lat,lng) {
          console.log(lat,lng)
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            map: map,
        });
        markersArray.push(marker);
}
`

It doesn't show anything on console?

Comment: And if you put console.log(data.key) after your success function of the ajax request?

Comment: How about to trigger the getLocations() function first. I see now that in your code you aren't firing it. Call it after you created the marker; getLocations();

Comment: well that was stupid mistake.... but now i get error:

`ReferenceError: markersArray is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

...pc]&&(c.galleryImg="no");e.b?um(c,e.b):(qk(c[A],"0px"),Mj(c[A],"0px"),Vj(c[A],"0...`

Comment: Just declare it in the top; var markersArray; But I think you can comment the line, because your example doesn't make use of it!